# Wordpress category description in frontend with shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this code to display category description in frontend:

```
    <?php 
the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' ); 
?>
```

But in admin where is the description I want to put shortcode that can be displayed in frontend. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can try adding following code in your active themes functions.php
2. For categories:

   add_filter( 'category_description', 'do_shortcode' );
3. For Taxonomies:

   add_filter( 'term_description', 'do_shortcode' );
4. For tags:
   add_filter( 'post_tag_description', 'do_shortcode' );

Let me know if it works..

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `Admin Dashboard > Posts > Categories`
- There click on the category whose description you want to update.
- Update the description on the new page that loads and save.

Comment: It's custom post type category and doing just what you say won't show the shortcode I inserted there. It's able to show text but not shortcode (like widgets for example).

Comment: Have you tried this function `get_the_post_type_description()` ?

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to do [link](https://screenshots.firefox.com/SULNTxOz1npr7ZBH/motoresnorte.es) adding `get_the_post_type_description()` to my taxonomy.php file doesn't solve the issue.  [link](https://screenshots.firefox.com/Nk4wIWLfeIDd0IZN/motoresnorte.es)